# -bash: gulp: command not found

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, npm-install

I am unable to run gulp. I have install gulp globally using `sudo` since I'm running on OS X EL Capitan. In my project under the folder `node_modules` I am able to see the gulp folder. However when I run on terminal `gulp` the output is `-bash: gulp: command not found` I don't seem to find the issue. Here is an image showing the commands to install Gulp and the output.
[image]

I tried to uninstall gulp globally by running `npm uninstall -g gulp` but I get the following errors.[image]

Comment: can you do an `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: @DjoryKrache after running `echo $PATH` the output is ```/Users/stevenaguilar/.rbenv/shims:/Users/stevenaguilar/.rbenv/bin:/Users/stevenaguilar/.rbenv/shims:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:/usr/local:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:/Users/stevenaguilar/.rvm/bin```

Comment: did you use sudo when you tried to uninstall?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell No,but i will try to use `sudo`

Comment: Can you do an `npm config get prefix`

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell it work in deleting it. I will try to reinstall

Comment: @DjoryKrache here is the output `npm config get prefix`
/`Users/stevenaguilar/.npm-packages`

Comment: try https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/wiki/Installing-global-node-modules-(Linux-and-Mac)#2-another-option-change-your-npm-prefix-to-somewhere-that-your-user-has-permission-to-write-to

Comment: node installed your gulp somewhere inside **/Users/stevenaguilar/.npm-packages** and there is nothing like this in your **$PATH**, find the folder used with this prefix, add it in your path and that's good.

Comment: I runned `npm config set prefix=$HOME/node` then I added to `.profile` the following code. `export PATH=$HOME/node/bin:$PATH` then I went to terminal and runned `gulp` still not working.

Comment: @DjoryKrache I open `.npm-packages` on atom  on a sub folder `bin` there is a file gulp. When I open gulp the following code is there `#!/usr/bin/env node` `'use strict';

require('../')();`

Comment: @DjoryKrache how could I add it to my $PATH?

Comment: When you type the command *gulp*, the system search in all the folders in your $PATH the executable file *gulp*. You just give it to your PATH like this

> *export PATH="/Users/stevenaguilar/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"`*
 -> check that I made no mistake on the folder name.

Comment: @DjoryKrache it worked

Comment: Just keep the command in your .profile to maintain the configuration